# Concatenar ficheiros de acordo com a ordem da lista C#

Tags: c#, lista, pdf, classificação

Eu tenho um programa que faz a concatenação de ficheiros PDF. Primeiro ele faz o `SPLIT` de todas as páginas de cada ficheiro e guarda-as numa pasta temporária. Quando carrego no botão final, chama uma função `GetFiles()` que vai buscar todos os ficheiros dessa pasta temporária e junta-os num só ficheiro PDF.

Tenho também uma lista com os nomes dos ficheiros e consigo ordená-la através de [Drag&Drop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/805267/11022675), mas eu queria que fosse possível ordenar a ordem de concatenação. Por exemplo, na lista está

- ficheiro 1;
- ficheiro 2;
- ficheiro 3.

E se o utilizador mudar para

- ficheiro 2;
- ficheiro 3;
- ficheiro 1.

Então vai concatenar por essa ordem e não pela ordem da pasta. 
Será que devia apresentar todas as páginas de cada PDF na lista e ordenar por aí ou existe outra maneira possível?

***EDIT (código):***

Função para fazer `SPLIT`:

```
        public void SplitPDf(string filename)
        {
        // Open the file
        PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(filename, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

        string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
        for (int idx = 0; idx<inputDocument.PageCount; idx++)
        {
            // Create new document
            PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();
            outputDocument.Version = inputDocument.Version;
            outputDocument.Info.Title =
            String.Format("Page {0} of {1}", idx + 1, inputDocument.Info.Title);
            outputDocument.Info.Creator = inputDocument.Info.Creator;

            // Add the page and save it
            outputDocument.AddPage(inputDocument.Pages[idx]);
            outputDocument.Save(String.Format(@"E:\temporario\{0} - Page {1}_tempfile.pdf", name, idx + 1));
        }
```

Função para fazer concatenação (`MERGE`):

```
        public void MergePDF(string folder)
        {
        string[] files = GetFiles();

        // Open the output document
        PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();

        // Iterate files
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            // Open the document to import pages from it.
            PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(file, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

            // Iterate pages
            int count = inputDocument.PageCount;
            for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
            {
                // Get the page from the external document...
                PdfPage page = inputDocument.Pages[idx];
                // ...and add it to the output document.
                outputDocument.AddPage(page);
            }
        }

        // Save the document...
        outputDocument.Save(folder);
    }
```

Código da lista:

```
 this.listaPdf.AllowDrop = true;
 private void listaPdf_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
        if (this.listaPdf.SelectedItem == null) return;
        this.listaPdf.DoDragDrop(this.listaPdf.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
 }

 private void listaPdf_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
 {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
 }

 private void listaPdf_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
 {
        Point point = listaPdf.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        int index = this.listaPdf.IndexFromPoint(point);
        if (index < 0) index = this.listaPdf.Items.Count - 1;
        object data = listaPdf.SelectedItem;
        this.listaPdf.Items.Remove(data);
        this.listaPdf.Items.Insert(index, data);
 }
```

Função `GetFiles()`:

```
public string[] GetFiles()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(@"E:\temporario"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"E:\temporario");
        }

        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\temporario");
        FileInfo[] fileInfos = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.pdf");
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        foreach (FileInfo info in fileInfos)
        {
            //Just skip the protected samples file...
            if (info.Name.IndexOf("protected") == -1)
                list.Add(info.FullName);
        }
        return (string[])list.ToArray(typeof(string));
    }
```

Comment: Olá @Sofia. Edite a sua questão e coloque o código que já tem. Facilita bastante na compreensão do problema.

Comment: Vou adicionar o código!

Comment: Sofia, o código da lista é o mais importante para ajudarmos, acho interessante se você deixar ele na pergunta também ao invés do link. :)

Comment: Feito! O código da lista está completo aí.

Comment: Não identifiquei o evento onde o usuário altera a ordenação da lista... se você não armazenar essa informação e simplesmente buscar os arquivos no diretório, não tem como  a sua rotina saber em que ordem o usuário gostaria de concatenar

Comment: Leandro Angelo podia ser mais claro? Devo armazenar essa informação num array por exemplo? 
O utilizador altera a ordenação da lista através de DragDrop. Esse código está nos eventos "listaPdf_MouseDown", "listaPdf_DragOver" e "listaPdf_DragDrop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi esta questão após mais de 1 mês. Espero poder ajudar alguém com esta questão também!
Então passo a explicar:

**1.** Adiciono os ficheiros à `ListBox` (sem o caminho da pasta onde se localiza)

**2.** Guardo esse ficheiro numa pasta temporária

**3.** Quando for a fazer a operação, vou buscar os items dessa lista para uma lista criada no programa

**4.** Para cada ficheiro dessa lista, faz a ação que quero.

Por exemplo, a lista tem esses ficheiros:

1. exemplo1.pdf
2. exemplo2.pdf
3. exemplo3.pdf

Vou guardar esses nomes (`"o\caminho\da\pasta\temporaria\" + item`) na lista nova para depois compará-los aos nomes da pasta temporária. Assim, procura primeiro o ficheiro "exemplo1.pdf" e faz a ação, depois o ficheiro "exemplo2.pdf" e faz a ação, e por aí em diante.

Irei mostrar um exemplo de um código que eu fiz - Merge de PDFs!

Adicionar ficheiro na `ListBox`:

```
    private void add1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFile.Title = "Procurar ficheiros no computador"; //título da janela
        openFile.InitialDirectory = @"C:\"; //diretório inicial
        openFile.Filter = "Ficheiros PDF (.pdf) | *.pdf"; //filtro de ficheiros
        DialogResult resposta = openFile.ShowDialog();

        if(resposta == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (string file in openFile.FileNames) //para cada ficheiro aberto
            {
                string caminhoCompleto = file; //caminho completo do ficheiro

                SplitPDF1(caminhoCompleto); //separar o pdf pelas suas páginas
            }
        }
    }
```

Adicionar ficheiros da `ListBox` na lista:

```
List<string> l = new List<string>();
foreach (string f in lista1.Items)
    l.Add("temporario\\" + f);
```

Por fim, fazer merge dos PDFs:

```
    public void MergePDF2(string folder, string[] e)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] files = e; //a variável e vai ser l.ToArray()
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(folder, FileMode.Create))
            {
                var document = new Document();
                document.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());

                PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(document, stream);
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = null;                   
                document.Open();
                foreach (string file in files) //para cada ficheiro no array
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
                    reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(file);

                    pdf.AddDocument(reader);
                    reader.Close();
                }

                if (document != null)
                    document.Close();

                succed = 1;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            succed = 0;
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
```